# How to send Email without delaying the response in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have tried a lot of variations to return the response quickly to user and send email in background but failed. Here is one sample that I have tried,

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(callback => 
                // It is important to put this line inside try catch otherwise it might crash the process 
                client.SendAsync(message, message)
                );
```

When I put a break point on client.SendAsync, no respose will be sent to user until this line execute. So what is the proper way to send email in background without waiting for response.

**Update:** I think I got the issue, actually it's the VS debugger that stop the asp.net thread(suspend ) until you Step Through. The above code works for my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You could place the email in a Message Queue and process the actual sending of it in a separate service that reads from that Message Queue.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon the number and size of the emails, you might also consider writing them to a pickup folder as well. You can use a local IIS SMTP server to relay the mail through a smart host. In practice, this has worked very well for us.

Answer (score 1):

Send Email Asynchronously with ASP.NET http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-send-email-asynchronously-with-aspnet